# Update rows and column using openpyxl from python

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl

**Problem:** Add "(C)" or "(S)" in every column or row in an excel file by using openpyxl - python.

**Example of a patient record or list of exercises**
The list will have dozens if not hundreds of exercises for every (physical therapy) patient.

1. Exercise     Repetition
2. Running      5 minutes
3. Walking      10 minutes
4. Squats       3x12
5. curls        3x12
6. ....    .....

I want to add an indicator to the exercises:
(C) for Cardio
(S) for Strenght 
Note: There will be more indicators (~20). We have thousands of files of patients records that don't have any categorization.

For example, We want to add the (C) for Running:

1. A            B
2. Exercise     Repetition
3. (C) Running      Time minutes
4. (C) Walking      Time minutes
5. (S) Squats       3x12
6. (S) curls        3x12
7. ....    .....
   NOTE: Due to the table limitation A1 is Exercise B1 is Repetition, A2 is Running and B2 will be Time minutes,

This is how I am setting it up: 
Note: I am not allowed to install any package at the work computer. However, I am using openpyxl because it was already installed in the system.

```
## Load your work book into a global variable
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('ExcersiceList.xlsx')

## Read the sheets name for your entire workbook
wb.get_sheet_names()

## Create a variable for each sheet in the work book, to manipulate each sheet
sheet1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
```

In theory, I want to do this but for every row and column

```
## To add the strings to existing values in a cell, use the following
    varB2 = sheet1[‘A2’].value  ## assign the value of A2 to varA2
    sheet1[‘A2’] = ‘(C) ’ + varA2 ## this combines the value of A2 with (U)
    sheet1[‘A2’].value  ## you will notice a value change
    wb.save(‘ExcersiceList.xlsx’)
```

### NOTE: This worked well. However, we want to be able to loop through the entire columns and rows. I acknowledge I need another file or dictionary to mark all the exercises accordingly.

I tried to do a loop at  least for the rows:

```
##loop through sheet1 max row
for row in range(1, sheet1.max_row+1):
   st1 = '(c) ' + str(row)
   print st1enter code here
   wb.save(‘yourFileName.xlsx’)
```

However st1 = it is only being assigned not written back into the excel file.

I appreciate your time and guidance in advance. Please let me know if you need more information. However, please understand that I can't reveal real patient data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `cell` function, see [Accessing one cell](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#accessing-one-cell) in the documentation.

For example, assuming you've loaded the sheet into `sheet1` and the details are in column one:

```
for row in range(1, sheet1.max_row+1):
    cell = sheet1.cell(row=row, column=1)
    if cell.value is not None:
        cell.value = "(c) " + cell.value

wb.save('test2.xlsx')
```